# Search a Goverment Database automatically in PHP

Tags: php, search

I'm wondering if this is possible... In Ontario when a vehicle is transferred from one owner to another it needs to undergo an emissions test. The Ontario Government allows you search your car's history based on VIN, here:
http://www.driveclean.ene.gov.on.ca/ONPublicWeb/pages/vir/vehSearch.jsf?LOCALE=en_CA

Is there a way for me to build a query in PHP that checks that database and returns the date it was tested?  I'm new to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a RSS, XML or anything that you can query?

Comment: If your browser can do it, chances are the right PHP can do it too.

Comment: There is no RSS or XML that I'm aware of, hence my asking. I looked for an api but one doesn't exist so I didn't know the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, look at using PHP cURL: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php
Your webserver or host's PHP configuration will need to be setup with cURL enabled, you can check `phpinfo()` to verify.

cURL will allow you to perform POST/GET and even SSL requests to the form's submission page `http://www.driveclean.ene.gov.on.ca//ONPublicWeb/pages/vir/vehSearch.jsf`. with a POST parameter of `virSearchForm:VINId` = vinnumber, `virSearchForm:searchButtonId` = search, and `virSearchForm_SUBMIT` = 1

Then you will need to parse out the response for the information you are looking for.

The biggest issue with this method is as they update their site, you will need to update your script as well.

Without testing, if they utilize a form of CSRF it can not be accomplished, as most techniques require a session state to generate a random number on each page view to authenticate from the form submission page with the processing page.
However they do have a hidden form field `javax.faces.ViewState` that appears to be a CSRF token.

You can also check with their customer support to see if they have a formal web api that will allow you to send requests via http, similar to Google's API examples.

Comment: Great, thanks for this! I did look into an API and they don't offer one. Some of what you said was totally Greek to me but I'll look into it further. Thanks! :)

Comment: if you have questions on anything specific, let me know, and I will further elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

If the site provides an API, you may be able to add URL Query String items (e.g., &vin=123456789) and then scrape the resulting display page for the information you want.

If the site doesn't provide an API, but makes you fill out a form, I believe that there are various tools for generating inputs to a page, and then scraping information off the returned page. wget might do this (I'm not familiar enough with it to tell you for sure), and Selenium can do this (I believe it has a PHP language interface). I take it you want a completely "hands off" automated approach. How you do it will depend on whether this is a one-off or occasional job, or a production system, and whether you need to run it from a web site or from a PC.

Hopefully, the above information will be enough to get you looking in the right place. Keep in mind that the government site probably won't mind you doing this once in a while, but could get testy if you place a heavy load on their server. Check to see if they have any Terms and Conditions limiting or prohibiting what you want to do.

Comment: I've looked into this a bit and they don't offer an API unfortunately, but I'll see what I can do with this scraping technique. I do want a hands off approach, so this may work. I've created a web-app that dealerships are using for inventory management and this would be a handy feature to include.